# enabling query log for _all_ databases

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel you can enable query logging on a per database basis by doing this:

```
DB::connection('dbname')->enableQueryLog();
```

If you do `DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();` it'll only log queries in the default database.

My question is...  is there a way to enable query logging for *all* databases?

Comment: Not sure but you can try `DB::enableQueryLog()` or try to loop every connection and then call `DB::connection($connection)->enableQueryLog();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging), it says you could enable query logging with:

```php
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
```

The `connection` method simply retrieves the default connection if no name is provided. Therefore you could enable them all in a provider like `AppServiceProvider` by looping through the list of connections:

```php
foreach (DB::getConnections() as $connection) {
    $connection->enableQueryLog();
}
```